# Printing out a nested list of categories from Magento using a recursive function

Tags: php, magento

So I have the following code in /[my-theme-name]/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml as a proof of concept:

```
<?php
$Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$categories = $Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation->getStoreCategories();

function render_flat_nav($categories) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . $category->getCategoryUrl($cat) . '">' . 
                  $category->getName() . "</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = $category->getChildren();
            $html .= render_flat_nav($children);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    return $html . '</ul>';
}
echo render_flat_nav($categories); ?>
```

It works great for level 0 and level 1 categories but any categories that are more deeply nested are never printed out.

So `$category->getChildren()` can't quite be returning what I expect it to. Is there a method I can call that will work with my recursive function?

Comment: What does `$category->getChildren()` returns?

Comment: It returns a collection of classes, but I am assume it is different in some way to the collection returned by `getStoreCategories()`

Comment: Doesn't it return the children of the category? I don't know magento, try to check the document.

Comment: Maybe you can just use Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation#renderCategoriesMenuHtml (see http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html#renderCategoriesMenuHtml)? Why do you need an extra function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to the problem, but it could be sub-optimal:

```
<?php
$Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$categories = $Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation->getStoreCategories();

function render_flat_nav($categories) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . $category->getCategoryUrl($cat) . '">' . 
                  $category->getName() . "</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->entity_id);
            $html .= render_flat_nav($children);
            }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    return $html . '</ul>';
}
echo render_flat_nav($categories); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(257);    
         $_categories = $_category
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'))
                    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());

function render_flat_nav($categories) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . $category->getCategoryUrl($cat) . '">' . 
                  $category->getName() . "</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->entity_id);
            $html .= render_flat_nav($children);
            }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    return $html . '</ul>';
}
echo render_flat_nav($_categories);
```

Thanks to the above i managed to get this to work for a specific category id and this works with flat categories aswell.